# PHP version upgrade from 5.6 to 7.4 causing issue for mbstring.func_overload = 6

Tags: php, mbstring

I am upgrading the PHP version from 5.6 to 7.4 and it is causing an error related to the php.ini setting:

mbstring.func_overload = 6

The error is:
PHP Deprecated:  The mbstring.func_overload directive is deprecated in Unknown on line 0

This setting was used in previous version to handle multi-byte character issues.

We need to prevent the multi-byte character issues in future also.

What is the solution for this ?

Comment: The manual is very clear about this. *Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.*  The solution is to get someone to change existing code to use `mb_` functions and ensure developers of future code do the same

Answer (score 4):

Don't use it. It is deprecated since PHP 7.2 and removed in PHP 8. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.func-overload

If you want a future-proof solution, replace them all with the `mb_` version of the functions.